# How do I show floors to on a polygon using CesiumJs

Tags: cesium, 3d-model

I have a gltf 3D building model on cesium. I would like to color code the range of floors. i.e. 2-5 floor, red 5-10 blue etc. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You didn’t specify any format. Anyway I assume this is a gltf model and it must be styled properly before exporting to file, it’s not something you do using cesium.

Comment: any idea how to do the settings on 3dcitydb?